# Cypress run spec option not working with .spec.js files

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have 2 questions about the (npx) `cypress run` command.

1. Inside the default Cypress pre-configured project, I created a file with a simple Cypress test (`cy.visit(...)`, `cy.get(...)`, `cy.should(...)`). However, the file either works or doesn't, depending on its extension:

`npx cypress run --spec 'myTest.cy.js'` runs successfully.

`npx cypress run --spec 'myTest.spec.js'` gives the following error:

*Can't run because no spec files were found.
We searched for specs matching this glob pattern: [correct/path/to/myTest.spec.js]*

**.js** file extension gives the same error as **.spec.js.**
I saw many references using .spec.js as a correct file extension for Cypress to run single-file tests with the `--spec` option.
Is there any additional configuration to make Cypress recognize it? [The documentation I found](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Folder-structure) doesn't make any distinction among .js files.

2. Is the `cypress run` command able to take a path with **spaces**?
   One of my computer drives has a spaced name I can't modify, and using `cypress run` inside it gives the same error as in 1., with Cypress removing the quotes around the path to display it in the error.

I am using the latest Cypress version, 11.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have read in the docs, [Ref](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e)

> | Option | Default | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | specPattern | cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx} | A String or Array of glob patterns of the test files to load. |

the `.cy.js` extension is the default for specs (for  Cypress version, 11.2.0), and if you want to use something else you must configure it ***explicitly*** in `cypress.config.js.

Of course you can use spaces on the command line, but you ***must*** surround the value that contains the spaces with quote marks. This is because the space char is the delimiter char on any command line command, not just with Cypress.

Comment: I got confused for 2° since 1° was there as well - I was using the same `.spec.js` file. 2° works indeed with the quotes. Your edit shows the setting I was looking for, `specPattern`. The precise thing I needed in `cypress.config.js` was: `specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/{*.spec,.*cy}.js"`

Comment: Can't edit my comment... that thing I wrote was also wrong. Correct `specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/*.{spec,cy}.js"`. What even is this format called? Regexp? Didn't find any example of broadening this setting...

Comment: It's not regex, I think it's minimatch or glob pattern.

Comment: This pattern worked for me - specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/*.{spec,cy}.js"